# How to daemonize process?

Tags: unix, process, daemon

On my hosting account I run chat in Node.js. All works fine however my hosting timeout processes every 12 hours. Apparently when the process is deamonized it will not timeout and so I tried to demonize with:

1. using Forever.js - running `forever start chat.js` . Running `forever list` confirms it runs and `ps -ef` command shows ? in TTY column
2. tried `nohup node chat.js` - running `ps -ef` TTY column shows `pts/0` and PPID is `1`
3. I tried to disconnect stdin, stdout, and stderr, and make it ignore the hangup signal (SIGHUP) so `nohup ./myscript 0<&- &> my.admin.log.file &` with no luck. `ps -ef` TTY column is `pts/0` and PPID is anything but `1`
4. I tried `(nohup ./myscript 0<&- &>my.admin.log.file &)` with no luck again. `ps -ef` TTY column is `pts/0` and PPID is `1`

After all this process always timouts in about 12hrs.

Now I tried `(nohup ./myscript 0<&- &>my.admin.log.file &) &` and am waiting, but do not keep my hopes up and need someones help.

Hosting guys claim that daemon processes do not timeout but how can I make sure my process is a daemon? Noting I tried seems to work even though with my limited understanding `ps -ef` seems to suggest process is deamonized.

What shall I do to demonize the process without moving to much more expensive hosting plans? Can I argue with hosting that after all this porcess is a daemon and they just got it wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Upstart is a really easy way to daemonize processes
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

There's some info on using it with node and monit, which will restart Node for you if it crashes
http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit